# DAX formula to show not repeated values and count them

Tags: formula, dax, powerquery

I have a table with for which the column "CODE" has values like this:

```
FTRA2
BRB92
RBRB4
XYZ
SXM4
RBRB4
NLDR
XYZ
FTRA2
POEU
FTRA2
```

I currently have this formula

```
="[ Unique values " & DISTINCTCOUNT(MyTable[CODE]) & "] 
" & CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(MyTable[CODE]), MyTable[CODE] ,", ")
```

that outputs this:

```
[ Unique values 7 ]
FTRA2, BRB92, RBRB4, XYZ, SXM4, NLDR, POEU
```

I would like to show all the unique values and their count (except those with the string "XYZ") and below show how many "XYZ" values are, like this:

```
[ Unique values 6 ]
FTRA2, BRB92, RBRB4, SXM4, NLDR, POEU

[2 XYZ values]
```

In this case there are 2 "XYZ" values, but could be zero XYZ values too.

I'm using Excel 2016.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE1**

I get this error tryng Joe's solution.
[image]

**UPDATE2**

Joe, I was able to make work your first part modifying like this:

```
= VAR ExcludeValue = "XYZ"
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        "[ Unique values " & DISTINCTCOUNT(MyTable[Code]) & " ]"
        " & CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(MyTable[Code]), [Code], ", ")
        , MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue
    )
```

But when I add the second part it says this error

```
This formula is invalid or incomplete: 'Calculation error in
measure 'MyTable[Code]: The function COUNT takes an argument 
that evaluates to numbers or dates and cannot work with values 
of type String.'.
```

I also removed the UNICHAR since doesn't work on Excel.

**UPDATE3**

Joe's solution it works correctly after I modified the `COUNT(MyTable[Code])` to `COUNTROWS(MyTable)`

The final solution looks like this.

```
=VAR ExcludeValue = "XYZ"
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        "
        [ Unique values " & DISTINCTCOUNT(MyTable[Code]) & " ]
        " & CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(MyTable[Code]), [Code], ", ")
        , MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue
    )  & "

" & CALCULATE(
        "[" & COUNTROWS(MyTable) & " " & ExcludeValue & " values]"
        , MyTable[Code] = ExcludeValue
    ) & "
"
```

**Update4**

Print nothing when there is no "XYZ" values works with your IF() addition. I've tried to follow your logic to do the same when there is no values at all. I added an
IF() to count if `MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue` is greater than 0 and if true do original CALCULATE, if not BLANK() but doesnt work.

```
CountLabel = 
VAR ExcludeValue = "XYZ"
RETURN
IF(
    CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(MyTable), MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue) > 0, 
    CALCULATE(
        "[ Unique values " & DISTINCTCOUNT(MyTable[Code]) & " ]"
        & UNICHAR(10) & 
        CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(MyTable[Code]), [Code], ", ")
        , MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue
    ),
    BLANK()
    )
    & IF(
        CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(MyTable), MyTable[Code] = ExcludeValue) > 0,
        UNICHAR(10) & " " & UNICHAR(10) & 
        CALCULATE(
            "[" & COUNTROWS(MyTable) & " " & ExcludeValue & " values]"
            , MyTable[Code] = ExcludeValue
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

This is the final formula that works as expected. Thanks to Joe's help in this case.

```
=VAR ExcludeValue = "XYZ"
RETURN
    IF(
        CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(MyTable[Code]), MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue) > 0 && 
        MyTable[Count of Code]>0,
        CALCULATE(
            "
            [ Unique values " & DISTINCTCOUNT(MyTable[Code]) & " ]
            " & CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(MyTable[Code]), [Code], ", ")
            , MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
    &
    IF(
        CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(MyTable[Code]), MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue) > 0 &&
            CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(MyTable), MyTable[Code] = ExcludeValue) > 0,
        " 

        " &
        BLANK()
    )
    & IF(
        CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(MyTable), MyTable[Code] = ExcludeValue) > 0,
        CALCULATE(
            "[" & COUNTROWS(MyTable) & " " & ExcludeValue & " values]"
            , MyTable[Code] = ExcludeValue
        ),
        BLANK()
    ) & "
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** - Changed my formula from using `COUNT` to `COUNTROWS` based on feedback from OP.

**UPDATE 2:** - Add `IF` statement to formula to exclude excluded count when 0.

**UPDATE 3:** - Add `IF` statement to formula to exclude distinct count when 0.

---

I will say that I created this solution in Power BI, but Excel 2016 should have the same functionality when it comes to DAX (with minor tweaks).

I created a measure with your formula, and simply wrapped each piece (the distinct count, and the repeated count) with a [`CALCULATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) statement that is used to filter your MyTable down to the codes you care about.

I used a variable for the "XYZ" value in case that needs to be changed. Now you can simply change it in one place (at the beginning of the formula) and the rest of the formula will reflect that change.

I also used `UNICHAR(10)` to add the line breaks instead of counting on the new lines in the formula.

With the `IF` statements...

- The first will check if the distinct count of items not equal to the specified value is greater than zero. If not, it won't show anything.
- The second will check if the distinct count and the row count of the specified value are both greater than zero. If they are, it will add the line break.
- The third will check if the row count of items equal to the specified value is greater than zero. If not, it won't show anything.

The final formula is:

```
CountLabel = 
VAR ExcludeValue = "XYZ"
RETURN
    IF(
        CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(MyTable[Code]), MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue) > 0,
        CALCULATE(
            "[ Unique values " & DISTINCTCOUNT(MyTable[Code]) & " ]"
            & UNICHAR(10) & 
            CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(MyTable[Code]), [Code], ", ")
            , MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
    &
    IF(
        CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(MyTable[Code]), MyTable[Code] <> ExcludeValue) > 0 &&
            CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(MyTable), MyTable[Code] = ExcludeValue) > 0,
        UNICHAR(10) & " " & UNICHAR(10),
        BLANK()
    )
    & IF(
        CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(MyTable), MyTable[Code] = ExcludeValue) > 0,
        CALCULATE(
            "[" & COUNTROWS(MyTable) & " " & ExcludeValue & " values]"
            , MyTable[Code] = ExcludeValue
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
```

Here is what the result looks like (again, in Power BI).

[image: Result]

Comment: @GerCas I can test later today, but my guess is that you need to remove the "CountLabel" part of my formula. In PBI, that is defining the name of the measure and it looks like you set that in a different box.

Comment: @GerCas I have updated my answer based on your second update. You should be able to replace `COUNT` with `COUNTROWS`. If you receive any error with `COUNTROWS`, try removing the "[Code]" part of the parameter (i.e. leave it as just `COUNTROWS(MyTable)`.

Comment: @GerCas I have updated the formula in my answer to include an `IF` statement that will only show the second part when the number of rows is greater than 0.

Comment: I've added `&& MyTable[Count of Code]>0,` to first `IF` since was appearing `1` in cases that there is any value. Additionally I've removed `UNICHAR` since is not supported in Excel. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with something similar but slightly different using COUNTROWS instead of CALCULATE to filter the table for the unique item. Also I am just learning DAX so don't know if this is a "proper" way to do it, but it seems to work.

```
Measure = 
VAR Exclusion = "XYZ"
RETURN
"[ Unique values " & COUNTROWS(FILTER(DISTINCT(MyTable[CODE]), [CODE] <> Exclusion)) & "] 
" & CONCATENATEX(FILTER(DISTINCT(MyTable[CODE]), [CODE] <> Exclusion), [CODE] ,", ") &
"

[" & COUNTROWS(FILTER(MyTable, MyTable[CODE] = Exclusion))+0 & " " & Exclusion & " values]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your formula it seems to be counting correctly the "XYZ" values but is not printing the unique values that are different to "XYZ".

For example, where only there are 5 unique values, shows 23. I modified the input in original post, there are 2 RBRB4 and 3 FTRA2 values but the output should be the same. 6 unique values and 2 XYZ

Comment: Not sure, it's working for me even with the updated sample values. I did change the usage of Filter+Distinct to be consistent and it still works, but I don't know if that was a functional or just semantic change. I'm also using Power BI and not Excel, so can't say if this is a factor.

Comment: Probably there are a few differences between Power BI and Excel. Because Joe's solution is not accepted in Excel with UNICHAR. Thanks again for your help